# Extend SonataProject? Form fields or different forms for custom ROLES. Symfony 2 + FOSUserBundle + SonataUserBundle

Tags: symfony

I have a problem. I have already installed
into my Symfony 2 FOS User Bundle and Sonata User Bundle with all dependencies.

Configuration have done and I can manage my users and roles.

But, I am going to create other form to add / edit users in my panel
for diferent ROLE. How can I do that?

Create multiple forms for each role and check it in Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController?

Remove / add fields in form when is it creating?

Any ideas?

Comment: In your title, please describe the question rather than listing components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also have done something like

1. extend the normal crud controller,
2. change into your service the name of the controller you want to use (not sonata_crud but the controller you created in the step before)
3. in that new controller create an action for the newSpecialRoleAction and createSpecialRoleAction with your code with their corresponding views

...from what i remember

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way..

In base_edit.html.twig from Sonata Bundle I have 
if statement, which check for me, that user has appropriate role
to show concrete fields in form.

It's "hard coding", but I didn't invent anything else.

Any other ideas?